# Injection: Unknown Interpreter (Injection.General)

Tags: c#, code-injection

WhiteHat Sentinel Scanning Report says - Injection: Unknown Interpreter (Injection.General) at

**fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);**

**Language: C#**  -
I have no idea. please help me to mitigate this issue - Injection: Unknown Interpreter:

Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Util;
using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Core;
namespace SampleAppendersApp.Appender
{
    public class PatternFileAppender : AppenderSkeleton
    {
    public PatternFileAppender()
    {
    }

    public PatternLayout File
    {
        get { return m_filePattern; }
        set { m_filePattern = value; }
    }

    public Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return m_encoding; }
        set { m_encoding = value; }
    }

    public SecurityContext SecurityContext 
    {
        get { return m_securityContext; }
        set { m_securityContext = value; }
    }

    override public void ActivateOptions() 
    {   
        base.ActivateOptions();

        if (m_securityContext == null)
        {
            m_securityContext = SecurityContextProvider.DefaultProvider.CreateSecurityContext(this);
        }
    }

    override protected void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) 
    {
        try
        {
            // Render the file name
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            m_filePattern.Format(stringWriter, loggingEvent);
            string fileName = stringWriter.ToString();

            fileName = SystemInfo.ConvertToFullPath(fileName);

            FileStream fileStream = null;

            using(m_securityContext.Impersonate(this))
            {
                // Ensure that the directory structure exists
                string directoryFullName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

                // Only create the directory if it does not exist
                // doing this check here resolves some permissions failures
                if (!Directory.Exists(directoryFullName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryFullName);
                }

                // Open file stream while impersonating
                **fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);**
            }

            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, m_encoding))
                {
                    RenderLoggingEvent(streamWriter, loggingEvent);
                }

                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.Error("Failed to append to file", ex);
        }
    }

    private PatternLayout m_filePattern = null;
    private Encoding m_encoding = Encoding.Default;
    private SecurityContext m_securityContext;
}
```

}

Comment: anyone please help me to fix this issue.........

Comment: So no one is here to explain about  Injection: Unknown Interpreter (Injection.General)